# C - Read and parse method not getting second line of input

Tags: c, parsing, matrix, io, strtok

I'm writing a program that deals with systems of equations I store into a Matrix struct. The intent is to read a line in the format

```
1 2 3, 2 3 4
```

and have that be the equivalent of

> x + 2y = 3
>
> 2x + 3y = 4

Currently it only stores

> x + 2y = 3

into my matrix.

I have a kind of blueprint that I usually use for parsing input in C but I had to deviate from it a bit to conform to this assignment, I'm guessing something is going wrong with the inner loop's tokenization process and that is destroying the original input.

Relevant code:

```
#define delims " \t\r\n"

Matrix createMatrix()
{
    Matrix m = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));

    char *input, c;
    int len = 0, max = 1;

    char *row, *coeff;

    int rows = 0, cols;
    bool set = false;

    printf("\n: ");

    input = malloc(max);

    // get input from user
    while ((c = getc(stdin)) != '\0' && c != '\n')
    {
        input[len++] = c;

        if (len == max)
        {
            input = realloc(input, 2*max);
            max *= 2;
        }
    }

    // parse input into equation by (,) delimiter
    row = strtok(input, ",");

    do
    {
        cols = 0;

        // parse equation into coefficients by space delimiter
        coeff = strtok(row, delims);
        setCoeff(m, rows, cols++, atoi(coeff) / 1.0);

        while ((coeff = strtok(NULL, delims)) != NULL)
        {
            setCoeff(m, rows, cols++, atoi(coeff) / 1.0);
        }

        coeff = strtok(NULL,delims);

        rows++;

        if (!set)
        {
            setCols(m, cols);
            set = true;
        }
        else
            assert(cols == m->cols);

    }
    while ((row = strtok(NULL, ",")) != NULL);

    row = strtok(NULL, ",");

    setRows(m, rows);

    return m;
}
```

Matrix.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef MATRIX_H_INCLUDED
#define MATRIX_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct Matrix
{
    int rows;
    int cols;
    double coeff[26][27];
} *Matrix;

void setRows(Matrix m, int r);
void setCols(Matrix m, int c);

void setCoeff(Matrix m, int row, int col, double val);

#endif // MATRIX_H_INCLUDED
```

Matrix.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Matrix.h"

void setRows(Matrix m, int r)
{
    m->rows = r;
}

void setCols(Matrix m, int c)
{
    m->cols = c;
}

void setCoeff(Matrix m, int row, int col, double val)
{
    m->coeff[row][col] = val;
}
```

Comment: Your input code does not null terminate the string as far as I can see.  It also doesn't handle EOF.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `strtok` twice: once to read comma separated data, then inside to read the values. Your while condition will use the latest pointer given to it, which is the value reader, so it can't find any more rows for you.

You'll have to either read the rows first and then the values or use separate methods for these, not `strtok` for both.

Comment: I figured that was the case. I'll modify this method and report back.

Answer (score 2):

`strtok` maintains internal state to keep track of where it left of.  This is why you're supposed to pass the original string the first time you call it but call it with `NULL` on subsequent invocations.  You're trying to interleave independent calls to `strtok`, so it will not be able to make the proper distinction between the first call and subsequent calls.

You instead could try to use `strtok_r` (a re-entrant version of `strtok` specified by POSIX that does not rely on global state, thereby avoiding this problem; on Windows, the equivalent function is `strtok_s`) or `strsep` if your platform supports them; neither is part of standard C.

If you require portability, you will instead need to restructure your code so that you perform your parsing phases separately: completely parse all `','`-delimited tokens first, keep track of the results, and then as the second phase, parse `' '`-delimited tokens from each of the previous results.